# Usage of shortly: "I will send it shortly"

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

Can I use the word shortly in this sentence:

> - Did you send the email ?
> - No, not yet , *I will send it **shortly***

Comment: Note that you can say *"in this sentence"* or *"in a sentence such as this"*...but not *"in this such sentence"*

Comment: You can use it. The word "shortly" means "in or within a short time".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - Did you send the email?
> - No, not yet, I will send it shortly.

This is acceptable, though if using this form people would often be using it as part of mentioning who it will be sent to.  For instance: *"I will send it to him shortly."*

More common when not specifying the recipient would be:

- "I will send it in a second" *(very soon, but realistically this often means in 60 seconds or possibly more)*
- "I will send it in a minute" *(generally same meaning as "shortly"...some number of minutes, usually)*

Comment: Other common replies might include: "I will send it soon" or "I will send it as soon as I can."